# Induced representation of A4 derivative group representation

Tags: representation-theory

Question: Let $G=A_4$, $H=G^{’}$, i.e. $H=\{1, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$. Let $\rho$ be any non-trivial $1$-dim complex representation of $H$. Claim: The induced representation $\rho^{G}$ of $\rho$ is irreducible.
Although the complex representations of $H $ and $G$ are clear, I would like to use the Frobenius reciprocity law to solve this problem. $H$ is a conjugate class in $G$, so I calculated that $\chi_{\rho^{G}}(1)=3\chi_{\rho}(1)$, $\chi_{\rho^{G}}((12)(34))= \chi_{\rho^{G}} ((13)(24))= \chi_{\rho^{G}} ((14)(23))=-1$. So I have $(\chi_{\rho^{G}}, \chi_{\rho^{G}})=(\chi_{\rho}, \chi_{\rho^{G}|_{H}})=\frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{g\in H}\chi_{\rho}(g)\overline{\chi_{\rho^{G}}(g)}=3$. This is in contradiction to irreducibility. May I ask if there is any problem with my calculations above.

Comment: How did you get $12$ as the sum (without the factor $1/|H|$)? One of the four terms has absolute value three, the rest have absolute value $1$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that $\rho$ is non-trivial, so it takes the value $-1$ at exactly two out of the three non-identity elements of $H$. So the latter inner product is
$$
\frac1{|H|}\sum_{g\in H}\chi_{\rho}(g)\overline{\chi_{\rho^G}(g)}
=\frac14\left(1\cdot3+1\cdot(-1)+(-1)\cdot(-1)+(-1)\cdot(-1)\right)=1.
$$

Comment: Oh, no, I made a mistake when splitting the formula! Thanks.